# Multiple A/D Converters reading from the same sensor in a race car

Tags: voltage-regulator, sensor, adc

I have a production based race car and my goal is to log the outputs of some OEM sensors used by the Engine Control Unit with an aftermarket data logger without risking any impact to the OEM function.

Presumably because the 12V system on a car can be anywhere from ~11-15V depending on load/charge state of the battery/alternator output, the ECU has a regulated 5V output to power sensors and a dedicated ground for these circuits. A 'signal ground' wire is run all the way back to the ECU for each 5V sensor (as opposed to just grounding to the chassis at the nearest point, like most automotive electronics).

I would like to log the output of the throttle position sensor to an aftermarket datalogger which has a very similar setup to the OEM ECU. It accepts a wide voltage range, and has a its own regulated 5V output for sensors. Usually the logger has its own dedicated aftermarket 5V sensors independent of any OEM system.

[image: tapping analog sensors for logging]

My question is should the respective sensor grounds be tied together when the 5V supply from the logger is not being used to power the sensor? It seems possible to me that depending on how these 5V supply circuits are designed, they might not have the same 0V reference relative to each other and blindly tying them together might negatively impact the ECU function.

In practice, only tapping into the sensor output and leaving the logger sensor ground floating for that channel seems to work fine. If there is a delta in ECU sensor ground and logger sensor ground, it seems possible to calibrate a new 0 point from the logger's perspective within its software. For example, if there is a sensor ground delta of 0.5V and 0% throttle is 1V, than the logger can be configured to register 1.5V as 0% throttle. The counter point is quite a few techs bridge the grounds of these separate regulated systems and that also seems to work in the real world as well.

I'd really love some insight from an EE perspective as to why one might only tap the signal and leave the ground floating, bridge the grounds of both regulated 5V systems, or avoid doing this all together and just eat the cost of running a parallel sensor for the logger.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the logger a balanced differential input or single -ended. Normally you would never share sensor ground with 5V power ground, even at the ECU, unless you were sure to have a good signal/noise ratio, although throttle current ought to be noise free, it might induce a DC offset but very small.

Comment: Some types of ADC (SAR) can disrupt high-impedance sensors during the tracking interval. Not a problem as long as there is enough tracking time and no other ADC measuring. Otherwise be sure to use a good buffer to prevent SAR kickback from disrupting the ECU.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, the 5V supply and sensor ground in this case are specifically designed for this purpose. The 5V supply isn't used for anything other than to power and those sensors are always grounded to the 'sensor ground' pin on the ECU. That is how the manufacturer has it setup. The logger is a single input. Real world data collection does seem to indicate that if there is any DC offset it impacts measurements by the logger no more than ~5%.

Comment: @MarkU, interesting both the logger and ECU are black boxes, so I have no idea what type of ADC is being used. Looking at the data sheet for an STM automotive MCU (which very well could be used in an ECU) it looks like they do use SAR type ADCs. So it seems to be a case worth considering. If SAR ADCs are used, would kickback be visible on an oscilloscope sample of the signal output while both ADCs are connected and sampling?

Comment: SAR ADC kickback may be observable on an oscilloscope, if the source is somewhat high impedance (like 1000's of ohms or more). It does depend also on the RC time constant of the SAR's sampling array and input switch. Extending acquisition time is one way to cure it, the other way is to use a buffer (like an op-amp) to drive the ADC input. The buffer will add some of its own noise and distortion, but a good *precision, rail-to-rail* op amp should do more good than harm. And offset/gain errors are easy to remove, as long as there's not much non-linearity or noise.

Comment: Which are you doing? Single sensor read by several devices or multiple sensors reading separate devices? Title says former & body says latter…

Comment: @SolarMike to clarify, its several devices reading the same sensor. (I say 'sensors' because despite me trying to tap into a single sensor the engine has many sensors sharing the same 'sensor ground' and 5V supply)